# Finding a closed form expression for $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\csc{\frac{i\pi}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Consider
$\displaystyle{S =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\csc\left(k\,{\pi \over n}\right) =
\frac{1}{\sin\left(\pi/n\right)} +
\frac{1}{\sin\left(2\pi/n\right)} +
\frac{1}{\sin\left(3\pi/n\right)} + \cdots +
\frac{1}{\sin\left(\left[n - 1\right]\pi/n\right)}}$

How can we find a general formula for $S$ using trigonometry identities or complex numbers ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let we assume for first that $n$ is an odd number, $n=2N+1$. In such a case the given sum is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N+1}\right)} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N+1}\right)}=\frac{4N+2}{\pi}H_N+2\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left[\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N+1}\right)}-\frac{1}{\frac{\pi k}{2N+1}}\right] $$
and $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{x}$ is an integrable function on the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, whose integral equals $\log\frac{4}{\pi}$.$^{(*)}$
By Riemann sums is follows that:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N+1}\right)} = \frac{4N}{\pi}\left[H_N+\log\frac{4}{\pi}\right]+O(\log N).$$
In the general case we get that the given sum behaves like $Cn\log n$.

---

$^{(*)}$ Since $\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x},x=k\pi\right)=(-1)^k$, by Herglotz' trick we have
$$\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{x-k\pi}+\frac{1}{x+k\pi}\right)(-1)^k $$
and by termwise integration
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx = \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^k \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4k^2}\right) $$
so $I=\log\frac{4}{\pi}$ by simplifying the partial sums of the last series and recalling [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: Does your sum not blow up?

Comment: @RonGordon: the given sum behaves like $n\log n$ hence yes, it does blow up.

Comment: No, I mean actually blow up.  Look at the first sum when $k=2 N$.

Comment: @RonGordon: oh, sorry, wrong summation indices. Now fixing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you explain about $H_N$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: $H_N$ is the $N$-th harmonic number, defined by $$H_N = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k} $$ and behaving like $\log(N)+\gamma$.

Comment: I just separated the "singular part" from the "regular part" and estimated them both with decent accuracy.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  What about $O(log N)$ ? Is it approximation ?

Comment: @S.H.W: well, $O(\log N)$ means $O(\log N)$. Such term comes from neglecting the contribute given by $\frac{2}{\pi}H_N$ in the first line.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Your answer is very good and fantastic  but do you know any more simple answer using trigonometry or complex numbers ?

Comment: @S.H.W it won't get any simpler

Comment: @S.H.W: the behaviour of your sum depends (almost only) on the singular part, that is not a trigonometric series, it is just a partial sum for the harmonic series. Despite its appearance, this question is not really related with trigonometric/complex number identities, it is about understanding the consequences of a non-integrable singularity for a positive real function.

Comment: Okay , Thanks a lot for your help.