# Finding a closed form expression for $S=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\csc({\frac{\pi}{i}})$ or approximation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, approximation, approximate-integration

Consider $S=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\csc({\frac{\pi}{i}})$

How can we find a general formula for S
using trigonometry identities or complex numbers ?

If a closed from cannot be found then how can we approximate it?

This is quite similar [Finding a closed form expression for $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\csc{\frac{i\pi}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103259/finding-a-closed-form-expression-for-sum-i-1n-1-csc-fraci-pin?rq=1)

Comment: What do you think happens when $i=1$?

Comment: @Peter Foreman ComplexInfinity perhaps a typo copying over latex from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103259/finding-a-closed-form-expression-for-sum-i-1n-1-csc-fraci-pin?rq=1 thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\, S_n := \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \csc(\pi/i). \,$
Note the Laurent series expansion in powers of $\,1/i\,$:
$$ \csc\left(\frac{\pi}i\right) = \frac{i}{\pi} + \frac{\pi}{6i} + 
\frac{7\pi^3}{360i^3} + O\left(\frac1{i^5}\right). $$  By summing we get
 $$ S_n \approx (n^2-2)/(2\pi) - C + H_{n-1}\pi/6 \quad \text{ where } \quad
C \approx 0.7.$$ We can get closer
approximations by using [generalized Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

Comment: thank you does this hold in the more general case of $\, S_n := \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \csc(\pi x/i). \,$?

Comment: @onepound Essentially yes because you just replace $i$ with $i/x$. The summation will be suitably modified.

Comment: Small typo in Laurent series: first term should have $i$ instead of $1$.

Comment: @ErickWong Oops! Fixed my typo. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot seem to get an expression for $S_n$ that includes x that works for different values of x other than 1 Perhaps I've got the sum wrong $S_n \approx (n^2-2)/(2x\pi) - C + H_{n-1}\pi/x6$ or if the range of the Laurent expansion is restricted to $0<|z|<\pi$ then this might only work around x = 0?